# Dynamic Linq to Select records with null value

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

[image]

Culture is dynamically selected, so that "Name_culture" param could be "name_en" or "name_it" and so on. That said, once culture is selected, all records where related Name_culture is NULL have to be filtered out.

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

IQueryable CountryTable = db.ISO3166
.AsQueryable()
```

This works:

```
.Where($"{Name_culture} = @0", "Guatemala")
```

This doesn't:

```
.Where($"{Name_culture} != @0", null)
```

ERROR:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseExceptionNo property or field '0' exists in type 'ISO3166'
```

Please note NOT using Dynamic Linq query (i.e. setting any fixed db field at compile time) returns expected result:

```
.Where(Where(i => i.name_it != null)
```

Returns all record BUT null, as expected.

How to compare a string to null in Dynamic Linq syntax?

Comment: Try casting null to string: ((string)null)

Comment: This can be done without using Dynamic Linq. See [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-6.0) method. `.Where(x => EF.Property<string>(x, Name_culture) != null)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this is neither a Core project nor I implement Entity Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
.Where($"{Name_culture} != null")
```